# CASE WHEN in SELECT statement in ORACLE

Tags: oracle10g

I have a table A, B, C which has many columns. Now I would like to join with some case condition, but the following query failed

```
SELECT   
QTY                          AS QUANTITY,
IS_UT                        AS IS_UT,
G_ACC_ID                     AS G_ACC_ID,
CR_AND_F_ID                  AS CR_AND_F_ID,
TRNG_ENRMT_ID                AS TRNG_ENRMT_ID
TRAINING_COURSE_ID           AS TRAINING_COURSE_ID
(CASE WHEN A.CR_AND_F_ID IS NULL OR A.CR_AND_F_ID = 0 THEN 
SELECT 
  A.CR_AND_F_ID                AS CR_AND_F_ID,
  A.IS_UT                      AS IS_UT,
  A.G_ACC_ID                   AS G_ACC_ID,
  A.CR_AND_F_ID                AS CR_AND_F_ID,
  A.TRNG_ENRMT_ID              AS TRNG_ENRMT_ID,
  t4.TRAINING_COURSE_ID        AS TRAINING_COURSE_ID
FROM T_E_P_LD
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_TRAINING t2
ON t2.TRAINING_ID = A.TRNG_ENRMT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TR_ENROL t3
ON t2.TR_ID = t3.TR_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TR_CLASS t4
ON t3.TR_CLASS_ID = t4.TR_CLASS_ID
ELSE A.CR_AND_F_ID
END) AS TEST 
FROM T_E_P_LD
```

I also tried to write Inline view but that too failed.

Please let me know how to approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding the error message to the question.

Comment: missing comma after training_Course_ID at first glance. also you can't have a case statement return multiple columns like that.  also you list A. in alot of the case query but A doesn't appear to be a valid alias on any of the tables; or a table untoitself.

Comment: @Mark, Thanks for your comment, I tried with aliasing a, but still it gives error like "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"...Could you please help me with the query.

Comment: How do I write an Inline View to achieve the same or With statement ?

Comment: SO is a great site to ask questions and get answers: Just be sure to provide a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before you ask a question consider [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Yes, I'm serious! To help us help you, generate sample data and expected results. [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) makes the output easy to read! You could also mock up data and the SQL tried using http://rextester.com/ or a similar site.  Pretty much anything is possible; it's a matter of should we do it; not can we.